# OSX Java Applet debug - See GET/POST

Tags: java, macos, web-services, applet

I have a applet in a webpage that I use and I would like to see the calls that it is making to a Web Service. Normally I would use Firebug or Charles for this, but those don't seem to notice the calls Java is making.

Anyone have a tool for this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, are the GET/POST calls encrypted by any chance? (over HTTPS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a network protocol analyzer like [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org). It will capture all traffic on your network device, then you will be able to filter only the packets in which you are interested.

Comment: See also [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), another network packet sniffer.